# How to combine each group in the union into single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following example data:

| id | username | group | unit | department | team | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t1 | active |
| 2 | user2 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t2 | active |
| 3 | user3 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t3 | inactive |
| 4 | user4 | g3 | u6 | d12 | t30 | active |
| 5 | user5 | g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | inactive |

And the following query which groups results by `active` and `inactive` per each selected group/unit/department/team, for example:

```
SELECT group
     , unit
     , department
     , NULL as team
     , COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM table
 WHERE group='g1' 
   AND unit='u1' 
   AND department='d1'
GROUP
    BY group
     , unit
     , department
UNION ALL
SELECT group
     , unit
     , department
     , team
     , COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM table
 WHERE group='g25' 
   AND unit='u54' 
   AND department='d70' 
   AND team='t88'
GROUP
    BY group
     , unit
     , department
     , team
```

this results in the following:

| group | unit | department | team | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | u1 | d1 | NULL | active | 2 |
| g1 | u1 | d1 | NULL | inactive | 1 |
| g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | active | 0 |
| g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | inactive | 1 |

Is it possible to turn each of the groups to a single row, i.e.:

| group | unit | department | team | active_count | inactive_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | u1 | d1 | NULL | 2 | 1 |
| g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | 1 | 0 |

Edit: I need to build the query based on arrays I receive, for example I can get the following arrays:

`["g1", "u1", "d1"]` and `["g25", "u54", "d70", "t88"]` and `["g3", "u6"]`. (You can assume that for each array you get the columns up to that level so if there is "unit" there will also be "group" for example).
Then the query would be:

```
SELECT group_
     , unit
     , department
     , NULL as team
     , count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
       count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
  FROM my_table
 WHERE group_='g1' 
   AND unit='u1' 
   AND department='d1'
group
    BY group_
     , unit
     , department
UNION ALL
SELECT group_
     , unit
     , department
     , team
     , count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
       count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
  FROM my_table
 WHERE group_='g25' 
   AND unit='u54' 
   AND department='d70' 
   AND team='t88'
group
    BY group_
     , unit
     , department
     , team
UNION ALL
SELECT group_
     , unit
     , NULL as department
     , NULL as team
     , count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
       count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
  FROM my_table
 WHERE group_='g3' 
   AND unit='u6' 
group
    BY group_
     , unit
```

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Nv2csSc8

Comment: Which DBMS is this ?

Comment: Why should the result not include the group g3?

Comment: @SelVazi SQL SERVER, @Jonas, this is example of data the user selected, so it might include group g3, but here the selected data was `g1,u1,d1` and `g25,u54,d70,t88`

Comment: Why are you making a duplicate of your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75138468/how-to-count-and-group-by-a-column-with-unknown-number-of-selections)?

Comment: @lemon sorry I just deleted it, because I thought it's vague and not understandable, here it's more precise of what I need

Comment: For this time it's fine, though when you have that impression, consider editing posts to improve their quality instead of deleting them and creating brand new ones. Check [ahmed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75145264/how-to-combine-each-group-in-the-union-into-single-row/75145644#75145644), they may have solved your problem.

Comment: @lemon thank you, will do next time. Looks like ahmed's solution is indeed working. I also see SelVazi solution. I am going to test them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the conditional count function instead of count as the following:

```
count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
```

According to the provided logic, I think you could rebuild your query without a union as the following:

```
select group_, unit, department, 
       case when group_='g1' then null else team end as team,
       count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
       count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
from table_name
where (group_='g1' and unit='u1' and department='d1') or
      (group_='g25' and unit='u54' and department='d70' and team='t88')
group by group_, unit , department,
         case when group_='g1' then null else team end
order by group_
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5H2SMX3)

Comment: thanks. I just thought the union structure is easier to construct programmatically where I need to do it dynamically with PHP. (I get array of the selections and I need to construct the query). Do you think I should use your option instead and convert the PHP to construct it like that? I get unknown amount of selections (each selection is an array of the group/unit/department/team). Do many `union`s slow down the query? Because a user might select like 50 selections at once

Comment: Mostly, union tends to create complex queries (less performance). For PHP you have to use parameterized query, and the number of parameters will be the same for both queries, right?

Comment: Normally with PHP yes, but I'm using Laravel so I believe I can actually build the string of the query exactly as seen above. Then Laravel will do all the PDO/SQL parametrization behind the scenes (I give it a string and it handles it). So what I need to do is programmatically write the query string not the actual PHP stuff (which might make it easier then to build your way as well)

Comment: It's worth to give it a try, test both queries and check if there is a noticeable difference between them.

Comment: thanks, now that I think of it, I can only use the first option dynamically if I use the "negation" of the `CASE`. What I mean is that I need to check if each column is not null then select it otherwise select null, because I get unknown selections, not only a selection where 'g1' is null. It can be any of them. Do you think it's possible to rewrite it like that in this case?

Comment: Could you share an extended data sample (with the union query) that covers this issue, I do not totally understand what you meant by *because I get unknown selections, not only a selection where 'g1' is null*

Comment: thanks! I updated the post at the bottom + added a demo

Comment: Yes, you could use the `IN` operator to match groups where a team should be null and add extra conditions in there where clause to get the added groups.  [see this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Eea22kO)

Comment: This is where I got stuck, because in my case I'd need to do `case` for each and every selection. If you look in your demo, then you chose `d12` with `g3` and `u6` but I only chose `g3` and `u6`. I'd need individual condition for each. I tried to convert your code to have CASE for each and every case but it's not correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/GUdRjMp0

Comment: Maybe you want to do it like this https://dbfiddle.uk/X7PBwchn

Answer (score 1):

I preserve your solution and made some updates on it using the conditional count on status :

```
SELECT _group, unit, department, NULL as team,
count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
FROM _table
WHERE _group='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1'
GROUP BY _group, unit, department
UNION ALL
SELECT _group, unit, department, team,
count(case when status='active' then 1 end) as active_count,
count(case when status='inactive' then 1 end) as inactive_count
FROM _table
WHERE _group='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88'
GROUP BY _group, unit, department, team
```

Demo here : https://dbfiddle.uk/OBD2Xob3

Comment: thank you, I chose the other answer because he did it before you so I saw it earlier, and in his demo there is another query similar to yours, so yours should be good as well, thank you. As I told him, in my case there might be dozens of selections so dozens of `UNION`s, do you think it will affect performance significantly?